# Progressed vs Advanced

Tags: difference

Please help me to choose the right word.

*I have progressed/advanced a lot in reading English books since I am attending this classes every day.*

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It is more common and natural to say "I have made progress in reading..." etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Progressed* and *advanced* could both be used in the same way, as far as I am concerned.

Nevertheless, [according to the ODE](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/progress), "Progress" refers to the *development towards an improved or more advanced condition*, while [advance](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/advance?q=advance) is to, in a more literal way, *to move forward* (although there's the meaning "to make progress".

I think it boils down to if you have a specific goal regarding your English. In that context, I would say that "Progress" is more appropriate.

Comment: Thank you AeroCross. By reading your comment I decided to rewrite my sentence. "I have made a lot of progress since I am attending this classes". Is this better?

Comment: @GATA Yes, that makes complete sense. You should be careful of that last bit though: "this classes" is grammatically incorrect: "this" is for singulars, and "classes" is plural for "class". You should either use "this class" (only 1 class) or "these classes" (several classes).

Answer (score 0):

The correct sentence should be:
"I have progressed a lot in English as I have been attending these classes every day." (and now I am able to read ...(such and such books)...
Using "Reading books" creates ambiguity (confusion) in mind of the reader, since books can be for beginner level as well as for advanced level.
Using advanced will indicate that you are far on in progress." My English classes are in an advanced stage.
Another suggestion which is less ambiguous:
"I am much more able in reading English books since I have been attending these classes every day".  Or (changing tense)...
"I am much more able in reading books since I am attending this class every day"...

Comment: I agree with the ambiguity. Please bear in mind that it should be "in **an** advanced stage", due to the word after the preposition beginning with a vowel (a).

Comment: "I am much more abled in reading English books" -- this is NOT correct English

Comment: thank you a lot , appreciate it....it should be able. Right?@Merk